# Is there a way to implement some gui (message box that asks for multiple inputs ie. registration document) into a code ive written

Tags: java, netbeans

I just want a simple popup message box that asks for multiple inputs and such.

```
System.out.println("Please enter  Name");
Name = name.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter  Age");
age=ages.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter  Gender");
Gender =gender.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter  Contact Number");
ConNum =number.nextLine();-->
```

Is there a way to make a gui for this? (its a foundation level project)

Comment: you need to install an external library like [fxml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FXML)

Comment: Hmm i would have to research more on how to use that but im somewhat pressed for time, i'm looking for more of a easy to implement with the code i have kind of thing. Thanks Tho :)

Comment: You can use Java Swing... Check JTextField, JPanel, JFrame, JDialog JLabel classes... Take some tutorials...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JOptionPane` to take your input:

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter  Name");
```

**Edit:**

You could ask the user all the questions on the one box (for this example, ensure they separate the answers by a *space*).

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter name.\nPlease enter age.\nPlease enter gender.");
String[] allInput = input.split("\\s+");
System.out.println("Name: " + allInput[0] + " Age: " + allInput[1] + " Gender: " + allInput[2]);
```

*Note:* obviously there will be issues, such as not using a space, or using a full name (Jack Sparrow) etc; but it gives you a general idea.

Comment: Yes but if i have multiple inputs and questions wouldn't that mean i would have multiple JOptionPanes?

Comment: You could ask all the questions in the one box, and then split the results into an array; `String[] allInput = input.split("\\s+");`, and print whichever part you want such as `System.out.println("name: " + allInput[0] + "age: " + allInput[1]);` etc...

Comment: Wow thanks ill definitely try it out thanks for the help !! :)

Comment: @JackWilliamDay have added a small code snippet; note the potential errors though.

Comment: Alright i got my thing up and running in a way i think satisfies my needs? xD Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As @notyou mentioned you can use `JOptionPane` it's very simple to implement it into you code check this example :

```
import java.io.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  

public class SystemOutDialog {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        // set up a custom print stream  
        CustomPrintStream printStream = new CustomPrintStream();  
        System.setOut(printStream);  

        // from now on, the System.out.println() will shows a dialog message  

        System.out.println("hello!");  
        System.out.println("how are you?");  
    }  
}  

class CustomPrintStream extends PrintStream {  
    public CustomPrintStream() {  
        super(new ByteArrayOutputStream());  
    }  

    public void println(String msg) {  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);  
    }  
}
```

Source [link](http://blog.codejava.net/nam/how-to-make-a-system-out-println-shows-a-dialog-message/)